# How to set fixed drawing speed and world steps in Box2D and SFML?

Tags: c++, box2d, sfml, game-development

There is a simple project, Box2D is engaged in physics, SFML draws. On different machines with different performance speed of the program varies. How to set a fixed speed? So that would on a powerful, average and weak computer the speed of the program (movement of objects) were the same?
We need to make Box2D work on different computers at the same speed.
It also gives coordinates, and SFML draws a square at the given coordinates. How to solve this problem?

Comment: You have to make it not to work as quick it can. For example run your physics only every 20 milliseconds.

Comment: @Öö Tiib, How? Can you make a delay before the step of the world through Sleep ()?

Comment: For example with std::this_thread::sleep_until (time_when_you_want_it_to_wake_up);

Answer (score 1):

**Constant Frame Rate** is what you're looking for. This is a well-known problem.

As you say, different machines will have different processor speeds. This could involve a computer with better hardware processes your *game loop* more times per second.

If you want to set a fixed frame rate, let say, 60 FPS, all you have to do is (as [Öö Tiib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54652634/how-to-set-fixed-drawing-speed-and-world-steps-in-box2d-and-sfml#comment96121159_54652634) pointed) **limit your updates** doing one update each *1/60* seconds.

This is a common implementation:

```
const sf::Time TimePerFrame = sf::seconds(1.f / 60.f);    // 60 FPS

void run(){
        sf::Clock clk;
        sf::Time timeSinceLastUpdate = sf::Time::Zero;
        while (_window.isOpen())
        {

            sf::Time dt = clk.restart();
            timeSinceLastUpdate += dt;
            while (timeSinceLastUpdate > TimePerFrame)
            {
                timeSinceLastUpdate -= TimePerFrame;

                processInput();
                update(TimePerFrame);
            }
            render();
        }
    }
}
```

This way, if a machine runs faster, you'll only update the state of your world 1 time every *1/60* seconds.

---

#### TL;DR;

When your program starts, `timeSinceLastUpdate` takes value `0`, you check the `while` and get the elapsed time since `clk` was created (or restarted), lets say that number *t1* is less than *1/60* seconds. The program add it to `timeSinceLastUpdate` and draw the scene, as it was created (an initial state of your game).

The second loop of your `while`, you get the elapsed time again (elapsed since last loop, because you restarted the clock). Lets call this time *t2*. Again, this number is less than *1/60* seconds, **but**, when you add it to `timeSinceLastUpdate`, both add up to a number greater than *1/60* (so `timeSinceLastUpdate = t1 + t2 > TimePerFrame`). This time, you will enter the second loop, and update your world as if *1/60* seconds had passed. You substract this *1/60* seconds from `timeSinceLastUpdate` and check again. If more than *1/60* seconds are remaining, you'll update again, until you stay *up to date*.

If you look careful, you only call `update(TimePerFrame)`, so you will always update your world by *chunks* of *1/60* seconds.

---

From [SFML Game Development Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849696845). *Chapter 1: Making Game Tick*

> #### Fixed time steps
>
> The solution we have come up with so far is sufficient for many cases. But it is not a perfect solution [...] since every frame is unique, and you can't guarantee that the delta time remains the
>   same. Consider that a frame may sometimes take three times the average
>   delta time. This can lead to severe mistakes in the game logic, for
>   example, when a player moves three times the distance and passes
>   through a wall he would normally collide with. This is why physics
>   engines expect the delta time to be fixed.
>
> The following is a figure describing the problem we are referring to:
>
> [image]
>
> What we will do now is use a technique called fixed time steps. We
>   write code that guarantees that in any circumstances, we always give
>   the same delta time to the update function, no matter what happens. If
>   you find that sounding difficult, there is no big difference from what
>   we already have. We just have to do some book-keeping in our code for
>   how much time has passed since we last called the `update()` function.
>
> *Code similar to the one above here, with the inner* `while (timeSinceLastUpdate > TimePerFrame)`
>
> The actual effect of this change is that we accumulate how much time
>   has elapsed in a variable `timeSinceLastUpdate`. When we are over the
>   required amount for one frame, we subtract the desired length of this
>   frame (namely `TimePerFrame`), and update the game. We do this until
>   we are below the required amount again. This solves the problem with
>   variable delta times, as we are guaranteed that the same amount of
>   frames is always run. In the application you can download, the logic
>   frame rate will be set to 60 frames per second by having the
>   `TimePerFrame` constant equal to `sf::seconds(1.f / 60.f)`.

Comment: *Delta time* or `dt` is a common definition (I think it comes from Maths and Physics) and can be seen as the minimum time the computer could take to update your *world/game/scene*

Comment: Great, that helped me.
But the speed of movement of objects what is slow how to increase it? Only increase the number of frames per second?

Comment: No, speed of the object should be something intrinsic to them. You have a box, which moves 600 pixels per second, if you update that box each *1/60* seconds, it will move 10 pixel per update. If you want it to move faster, increase its speed internally.

Comment: Thanks. Good luck.